# Choose option from select list using next/previous button with jquery

Tags: jquery

What is best way to navigate select option using next/previous button with jquery? I have a select list when change also changes some div. Instead of just a dropdown, I want to have a next and previous button on the left and right sides of the select list.

I cant really figure out, i tried attr but only working if I manually type the attributes.

```
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
<select id="mycars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and explain what particularly you have problems with.

Comment: do you want some kind of pagination with jquery??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `.removeAttr()`, `attr()`, `.next()` and `.prev()` methods for that.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/U4vaP/4/)

#### Sample

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').next('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mycars > option:selected').prev('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [jQuery.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [jQuery.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

### Update

I don't know if you want to disable the, for example, next button if the last element is selected, select the first one or do nothing. Please provide this information.

You can do this to go to this to go to the first element if the last is selected, or to the last if first is selected.

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    var isLastElementSelected = $('#mycars > option:selected').index() == $('#mycars > option').length -1;

    if (!isLastElementSelected) {     
        $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected'); 
    } else {
           $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
           $('#mycars > option').first().attr('selected', 'selected'); 
     }   
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    var isFirstElementSelected = $('#mycars > option:selected').index() == 0;

    if (!isFirstElementSelected) {
       $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
         $('#mycars > option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
         $('#mycars > option').last().attr('selected', 'selected'); 
    }

});
```

### [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4vaP/5/)

Comment: Working jquery 1.9.1 is not working properly. For example after clicking the next button and comes again the first option it stops and not continue to second option.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a nice short version that does not wrap around at either end:

```
$("#next, #prev").click(function() {
    $("#mycars :selected")[this.id]().prop("selected", true);
});
```

Note that it depends on the `id` of the buttons being `next` and `prev`, which they are in your example.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7eCKB/2/).

Using `prop` instead of `attr` means we actually change the property, rather than the value of the attribute. That means there's no need to use `removeAttr` as in the other answers, which means we don't get stuck on the first or last option.

Comment: But maybe you should change the selector to $("#prev,#next") then no extra class is needed and it won't cause any problems with other buttons on the page

Comment: @Tom - Yeah, that would make sense. Can't believe I didn't think of that in the first place, instead of suggesting a shared class name. Your suggestion has the added benefit of enforcing the `id` values to  be `next` and `prev`, which is obviously essential in this case. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

to set the selected value of a list you should try something like this:

```
$("#mycars").val("saab");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").next().val());
})

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $("#mycars").val($("#mycars > option:selected").prev().val());
})
```

Interestingly this will "wrap-around" (go back to the 'Volvo' option after 'Audi') when using the next button but stop at the 'Volvo' option when using the 'Previous' button. Here's a demo -

http://jsfiddle.net/aQSSG/

Comment: Not that surprising: If you set the value to something which does not exist in the options list, the first option is selected again. If one  of the values was an empty string, you would get a totally different behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/aQSSG/1/