# Iterate through select options with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, button

this seems like something that should be incredibly easy to do but it's early in the morning and I'm drawing a blank.

I have a select that contains % values (for zooming) and as well as having this as a dropdown I want to have two buttons (+ and -) to iterate through the list.

So assuming I had:

```
<button id="minusButton">-</button>
<select id="zoomSelect" onchange="zoom()">
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="50">50%</option>
      <option value="100" selected="selected">100%</option>
</select>
<button id="plusButton">+</button>
```

How would I go about switching up and down the select each time a button is pressed. Also ensuring it stops nicely on 100% and 10% (ie, no wrapping round or throwing an error if I keep pressing +).

Thanks very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You’re aware that a select field exposes properties such as selectedIndex and length, yes? So what more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#minusButton', function() {
  var selIndex = $("#zoomSelect").prop('selectedIndex');
  if (selIndex != 0) {
    $("#zoomSelect").val($('#zoomSelect option').eq(selIndex - 1).val());
    zoom();
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#plusButton', function() {
  var selIndex = $("#zoomSelect").prop('selectedIndex');
  if (selIndex != $('#zoomSelect option').length - 1) {
    $("#zoomSelect").val($('#zoomSelect option').eq(selIndex + 1).val());
    zoom();
  }
});

function zoom() {
  console.log('zoomed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="minusButton">-</button>
<select id="zoomSelect" onchange="zoom()">
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="50">50%</option>
      <option value="100" selected="selected">100%</option>
</select>
<button id="plusButton">+</button>
```

Click event can be written as such so as to change the value of select box, and trigger the zoom function accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> Pure JS answer

Basically you need to get `selectedIndex` and set that index.

`document.getElementById("zoomSelect").selectedIndex` will get what index is currently selected and you can set that based on Plus or Minus click.

```js
function zoom(isPlus) {
  var zoomSelect = document.getElementById("zoomSelect");
  var index = zoomSelect.selectedIndex;
  var length = zoomSelect.length;

  if (isPlus && (index < length - 1)) {
    zoomSelect.selectedIndex = index + 1;
  } else if (!isPlus && (index > 0)) {
    zoomSelect.selectedIndex = index - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="minusButton" onclick="zoom(false)">-</button>
<select id="zoomSelect" onchange="zoom()">
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="50">50%</option>
      <option value="100" selected="selected">100%</option>
</select>
<button id="plusButton" onclick="zoom(true)">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selectedIndex` to work with the selected item like

```js
var $zoom = $('#zoomSelect'),
  len = $zoom.find('option').length;;
jQuery('#plusButton, #minusButton').click(function() {
  var op = (this.id === 'minusButton' ? -1 : 1);
  $zoom.prop('selectedIndex', function(idx, value) {
    var x = value + op;
    return x < 0 || x > len - 1 ? value : x;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="minusButton">-</button>
<select id="zoomSelect" onchange="zoom()">
  <option value="10">10%</option>
  <option value="20">20%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
  <option value="100" selected="selected">100%</option>
</select>
<button id="plusButton">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a duplicate of this with an answer - [Choose option from select list using next/previous button with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112473/choose-option-from-select-list-using-next-previous-button-with-jquery)

So this can be closed.