# How to add a button that scrolls up and down through a multiselect list?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Similar to this question, [How can I move selected option in multiselect up and down by buttons using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713702/how-can-i-move-selected-option-in-multiselect-up-and-down-by-buttons-using-jquer) but not moving the selection up and down. But being able to scroll up and down a list without the scrollbar for more accurate scrolling. Similar to using the up and down keys to progress through the list one at a time up or down.
How can I achieve this with an up and down button with jQuery or JavaScript?

Or are there any HTML attributes that may aid in browsing a long list more user friendly?

```
<select id="selectLongList" multiple>
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
     <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Two buttons, maybe to the side

```
<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```

Update
After further looking I came across this solution, [Choose option from select list using next/previous button with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112473/choose-option-from-select-list-using-next-previous-button-with-jquery). This kind of replicates what I am trying to accomplish. But I'm not wanting to move the selection. I would just like to move through the list of options.

Borrowing from one of the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112759/2946802
>

> ```
> $("#next, #prev").click(function() {
>    $("#mycars :selected")[this.id]().prop("selected", true);
> });
> ```

Sort of like this in how it changes to the next value, but working with a multiple select and not changing the actual selection. Just moving on to the next value.

```js
$("#prev").click(function() {
   $('#selectLongList option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);

 });
    
$("#next").click(function() {
$('#selectLongList option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="prev">Previous</button>
   <select id="selectLongList">
       <option value="1">1</option> 
       <option value="2">2</option> 
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Select2 for jQuery, it will most likely solve your problem. 
You won't need to move any options. Select2 will just display every selected item inside the select itself.

[Select2 Docs Getting Started](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I’ve considered using the Select2 solution. But, it seems to not offer a solution if a list has a lot of entries and being able to navigate through the list with the mouse. Grabbing the scroll bar sections of the list can be easily missed. I’m looking for a solution that allows a person to tick through the list one at a time if needed.